# Vue Unit Testing - Mocking a plugins return value

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, vue-test-utils

I have a custom plugin that returns a boolean. Rather than importing the plugin to the test, I want to mock this value. I can mock the plugin easily enough, but how can I change the return value in the test?

```
const $mq = () => {};    
wrapper = shallowMount(Component, { 
  //...
  mocks: {
    $mq
  }
  //...
});
```

Test

```
it ('Test description', () => {
  wrapper.vm.$mq = () => true; // HOW TO MOCK PLUGIN RETURNS???
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incase anyone comes along this, you need to change the value before providing it to the mocks option.

```
const $mq = () => true;    
wrapper = shallowMount(Component, { 
  //...
  mocks: {
    $mq
  }
  //...
});
```